# Get Last Entry in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm basically trying to make a "goal" bar. The goal is determined by getting the last entry I made in a MySQL table. I want to get the ID of the last entry therefore.

How do I get the last entry in the table and then get the id from that last entry?

(Using PHP)

Comment: Do you have an auto incrementing field such as an `id`?

Comment: You need to record a timestamp to be sure you're getting the most recent entry.

Comment: @MichaelMior, Absolutely not!  Timestamp doesn't have anywhere near the resolution to guarantee this.

Comment: @cillosis Yes I do have an auto incrementing field and it's the id.

Comment: @Fogest, You aren't "using PHP" as much as you are using some sort of API for connecting to your database.  Which are you using?  `mysql_*`?  PDO?

Comment: @Brad For multiple updates per second sure.

Comment: @Brad Not quite sure what you mean... my mysql version is 5.1 if that's what you want to know?

Comment: @Fogest, Show some example code on how you connect to your database.

Comment: It's basically this: `$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);` and then the next lines check if connection worked. If it did then a table is selected from there, and data is added. Pretty much the basic way to connect, but no matter I have the solution and am about to test if it works.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To get the greatest id:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable
```

Then to get the row:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ???
```

Or, you could do it all in one query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I think others were making it a little more complicated then it needed to be. I guess my question could have been better. I simply needed the greatest id. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'll use the one Eric answered as but, this looks like it would work as well!

Comment: note about LAST_INSERT_ID: LAST_INSERT_ID gives the id of last row inserted by current connection, not the others.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this query to get the results you want with this sql query as used in this example:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM my_users_table ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will use Eric's, even though this would probably work!

Comment: It is fine, mate. I hope this thread solved your issue properly=)

Answer (score 3):

To do this reliably, you must have some field in the table that you can examine to determine which is last. This could be a time stamp of when you added the record, a sequence number that continually increases (especially an auto-incrementing sequence number), etc.

Then, let's suppose it's a sequence number called "rec_seq". You'd write something like:

```
select * from my_table
where rec_seq=(select max(rec_seq) from my_table)
```

Comment: Looks kinda like Eric's answer but I'm going to have to take Eric's answer!

Comment: No problem, his is slightly simpler, it's the easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

if the field is auto-incremented then you can use  [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: This assumes you have just inserted the row.

Answer (score 2):

select all fields from table in reverse order and set limit 0,1
This will give you last result of table field data

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest entry of a user

```
'SELECT user_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = '.$userid.' ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers show how to get the latest entry by id. If one uses non-incrementing ids such as UUIDs as keys, this does not work. In that case one could use a `created_at` column instead.

```sql
-- highest id
SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

-- latest created at date
SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```